# Как загрузить файл NodeJS

Tags: node.js, github

Как загрузить файл **NodeJS** на **гитхаб**? Самой-то проблемы загрузить нет, но как сделать, чтобы он там взаимодействовал с другими файлами?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под «взаимодействовал»? Если, что бы он выполнялся, то никак. github хранилище исходников, а не сервер.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, понял, спасибо)

Comment: Может быть вам нужен https://pages.github.com/ ?

Comment: @Total Pusher, а вы пробовали? У меня что-то не получается...

Comment: Нет, не пробовал. Знаю, что люди хостят гитхаб проекты там. Может и вам подойдет

Comment: @Total Pusher, скорее, как сказал Алексей, сервер запустить не получится. Но всё равно спасибо)

Comment: Я распознал вопрос, как хостить проекты на гитхабе. У них есть такая функция, но да, она подходит только для статики, [пример](https://unetbootin.github.io/). Тогда попробуйте [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/nodejs), там точно сервер ноды работает. Либо купите VDS, цены более чем доступные.

Comment: @Total Pusher, то, что нужно. Можете опубликовать ответом, отмечу как верный :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У GutHub есть функция публикации статики [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), например так опубликован [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

Если нужен бесплатный NodeJS хостинг, попробуйте [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/nodejs), там есть сервер ноды.

Альтернатива - [покупка VDS](https://poiskvps.ru/), цены более чем доступные.